# bind [!hidden] to select box option with Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm trying to add a show/hide behavior to a select box using Angular 2+ so basically I have :

```
 <select>
      <option disabled selected>Flow progres</option>
      <option *ngFor='let flow of flows'>{{flow}}</option>
    </select>

      <div [hidden]="true">
        <p>The flow progress is on going</p>
      </div>
```

and .ts:

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit{
    flows = ["Passed",'Waiting','In Progres',' Failed'];
}
```

so when "in progress" option will be selected I want to show that hidden div, otherwise the div will be hidden for the other options.

Comment: Use [ngModel] on select and put condition on div as [hidden]="yourngmodelvariable!=='In Progress'"

Comment: try using `*ngIf` for `in progress` and set [ngModel] on select

Comment: @Vivz put that as a comment to get your points ;) ty!

Comment: Ok I will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your HTML the following way. Import all your dependencies from angular core module.

```
<select [ngModel]="selected">
    <option disabled selected>Flow progres</option>
    <option *ngFor='let flow of flows'>{{flow}}</option>
</select>

<div [hidden]="selected!=='In Progress'">
    <p>The flow progress is on going</p>
</div>
```

Comment: one more thing, seems that disabled "<option disabled selected>Flow progres</option>" is not selected by default anymore, any idea ? It is in the list but not like selected.

Comment: Assign the default selected value to your [ngModel]

Answer (score 3):

Create a variable inside component.

```
public showHide:boolean = false; //Set default value if you like else not
```

Add onChange event on select like:

```
<select #t (change)="handleSelectedValue(t.value)">
      <option disabled selected>Flow progres</option>
      <option *ngFor='let flow of flows'>{{flow}}</option>
    </select>
```

in component write the function like this:

```
handleSelectedValue(value) {
 // Get and value and assign it to variable declared above 
     if(value == 'In Progres')
    this.showHide = true;

}
```

in your html bind this showHide variable to Div like this:

```
<div *ngIf="showHide">
        <p>The flow progress is on going</p>
</div>
```